# pip ALWAYS installs to /usr/local/lib/python2.7

Tags: macos, install, python

I cannot find a way to get a functioning pip3 on macos Big Sur.

I have tried standard python, HomeBrew python, and also pyenv/venv, following the directions and searching for issues in each case.

In every case I seem to have a successful installation, with python, and pip, in the correct place, and of the correct version. I started by removing /usr/local in each case, with the same result.

Nevertheless, in every case, pip installs packages to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Edit:

I just found that creating a fresh user account and using pyenv/venv works. So a config file is setting up a rogue symlink, or something.

Comment: Note you say pip3 in the first sentance and pip thereafter. pip will be python 2.7 - Try pip3 in the command line. To find pip try `which pip` also what is your $PATH in original and new user

Comment: I'm talking about pip3 in each case, the version installed with python 3.11.1. But the name 'pip3' is not a distinguishing feature anyhow, because there is a pip3 and python3 in /usr/bin also (python 3.8.9), plus all of the installs (standard, HomeBrew, pyenv) provide both 'pip' and 'pip3' for convenience if I remember correctly. For each user /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin in $PATH, or for pyenv /Users/$USER/.pyenv/shims comes first. The same problem occurs when I invoke pip with python -m pip. In each case python -V or pip -V gives the expected (correct) result, as does 'which pip(3)'